# Confused about this in ES6. It's equal to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, arrow-functions

I have this function call in jQuery:

```
image.save(comment);
```

and I've defined the save function like this:

```
Image.prototype.save = association => {
  debugger;
  this
}
```

How do I get `this` to equal the recipient of the function call which is `image`? Right now at the debugger, it equals the window object.

Comment: Well don't use arrow functions when you need a `function` as a *method*.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use arrow functions

> Arrow functions have a lexical `this`; its value is determined by the surrounding scope.

```
Image.prototype.save = function(association){
  debugger;
  this
}
```